# "Segmentation fault" when I make a call in main

Tags: c++, list, function, segmentation-fault, call

I have being having problems with this particular code, when I want to access to the data in lista->arch->`nombreArchivo` from main. The program crashes, when I debugged it I found out that the problem is a "segmentation fault"-type of error. I think I lack an allocation but I don't know where.

NOTE: What I want to do is to make a list (listaArchivo) of the `struct _archivo`, so maybe the error is in the function `insertarArchivoListaArchivos()`.

Here´s the main() code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <conio.h>

#include "Sistema.h"
#include "Archivo.h"
#include "Directorio.h"
#include "ListaArchivos.h"
#include "Constantes.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    /* VARIABLES */
    Cadena c_DIR=(char *)"DIR";
    Cadena c_CREATEFILE=(char *)"CREATEFILE";
    Cadena c_DELETE=(char *)"DELETE";
    Cadena c_ATTRIB=(char *)"ATTRIB";
    Cadena c_IF=(char *)"IF";
    Cadena c_DF=(char *)"DF";
    Cadena c_TYPE=(char *)"TYPE";
    Cadena c_CREARSISTEMA=(char *)"CREARSISTEMA";
    Cadena c_DESTRUIRSISTEMA=(char *)"DESTRUIRSISTEMA";
    Cadena c_EXIT=(char *)"EXIT";
    Cadena Segmento;
    Cadena comando;
    Cadena parametro1;
    Cadena parametro2;
    bool seguir;
    int contador=0;
    char frase[50];
    Archivo arch;
    ListaArchivos lista;


    do{
    cout <<"> ";

    /* ALGORITMO PARA DIVIDIR LA FRASE EN TOKENS */
    fgets(frase,50,stdin);
    Segmento=strtok(frase," ");
    while(Segmento!=NULL){
             if( contador == 0 ){
                 comando=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL COMANDO */
             }
             if ( contador == 1 ){
                  parametro1=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL PRIMER PARAMETRO */
             }
             if( contador == 2 ){
                 parametro2=Segmento; /* GUARDA EL SEGUNDO PARAMETRO */
             }
             Segmento=strtok(NULL, " ");
             contador++;
    }

    /* SELECCIONA EL COMANDO INDICADO, COMPARANDO LA CADENA COMANDO CON LAS DIFERENTES CADENAS */
    if (strcmp(comando,c_DIR)== 0){
        cout <<"Uso comando DIR"<<endl<<endl;
    }
    else{
        if (strcmp(comando,c_CREATEFILE)== 0){

            lista=crearListaArchivos(); //CREATE LIST OF ARCH.


            cout<<"LISTA CREted, SU DIRECCION ES "<< &lista<<endl;

            arch=crearArchivo(parametro1); //CREATE ARCH
            cout<<"ARCHIVO CREAted, SU DIRECCION ES"<<&arch<<" SU NOMBRE ES: "<<arch->nombreArchivo<<endl;

            insertarArchivoListaArchivos(lista,arch); //INSERTS ARCH IN LIST OF ARCHS

            cout <<" THE ARCHIVO IN lista es named ..."<<lista->arch->nombreArchivo<<endl<<endl;
        }  /*the problem seems to be when I make this call*/ 

...............................
...............................
...............................
```

Here´s the archivo header:

```
struct _archivo{  //aca declaro la estructura de un archivo
    Cadena nombreArchivo;
    Cadena Atributos;
    Cadena Contenido;
    _archivo *Siguiente;
    _archivo *Anterior;
};
typedef _archivo* Archivo;

/*
 * Crea e inicializa un archivo con nombre 'nombreArchivo'
 */
Archivo crearArchivo(Cadena nombreArchivo){

    //inicializo
    Archivo nuevoArchivo=new _archivo;

    nuevoArchivo->nombreArchivo=nombreArchivo;
    nuevoArchivo->Siguiente=NULL;
    nuevoArchivo->Anterior=NULL;
    return nuevoArchivo; //devuelvo el archivo inizializado
}
```

Here´s listaArchivos header:

```
struct _listaArchivos{ //defino la estructura _listaArchivos, que sera una lista de nodos de tipo Archivo, definidos en el header Archivo.h
    Archivo arch;
};
typedef _listaArchivos* ListaArchivos;

/*
 * Crea, inicializa y retorna una nueva lista de archivos.
 */
ListaArchivos crearListaArchivos(){
     ListaArchivos lista = new _listaArchivos;
     lista->arch=NULL;
     return lista;
}
/*
 * Inserta el archivo 'archivo' en la lista 'lista'.
 */
void insertarArchivoListaArchivos(ListaArchivos &lista, Archivo archivo){
    ListaArchivos cabezal;

    if (lista==NULL){
        lista->arch=archivo;
        lista->arch->Anterior=NULL;
        lista->arch->Siguiente=NULL;
    }
    else{
        cabezal=lista;
        while (!cabezal->arch->Siguiente)
            cabezal->arch=cabezal->arch->Siguiente;
        cabezal->arch->Siguiente=archivo;
        archivo->Siguiente=NULL;
        archivo->Anterior=cabezal->arch->Siguiente;
    }
}
```

What can I do? Meanwhile I'll just keep reading about pointers/lists and try to figure out.

Comment: Which line does your debugger say is causing the segfault?

Comment: Please don't shout. And please don't try to get people to play debugger for your.

Comment: The line which is causing problems is the one on the main() 
cout <<" THE ARCHIVO IN lista es named ..."<<lista->arch->nombreArchivo<<endl<<endl;
This one! Sorry Im not trying to make people debug my code, I want to know why it is crushing when I call that specific line

Comment: Please, take a look at the guide [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). It will help to improve your Question greatly.

Comment: Either `lista` or `lista->arch` is null (or otherwise invalid), or something else goes wrong inside the overloaded `operator<<`. It should be easy to spot the problem when you step through the code in your debugger, but very hard to guess from the code you've posted.

Comment: I suggest you remove the function code from header file into cpp file.  Any cpp file that includes the header will get a copy of the function and linker will say duplicate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues I found that may lead to your problem:

When using strings there is a difference between character zero, '0', and numeric 0.  You will need to convert the text representation of numbers to internal representation.

Since you tagged the question as C++, I suggest you use `std::string` and the `find` methods rather than the C function `strtok`.  Search StackOverflow for "[c++] parse number".

Use *named identifiers* instead of magic numbers.
For example use:

```
`#define MAXIMUM_ARRAY_SIZE 50`  
`//...`  
`char frase[MAXIMUM_ARRAY_SIZE];`  
`//...`  
`fgets(frase, MAXIMUM_ARRAY_SIZE, stdin);`
```

This ensures that you only have to change the number in one place and all the code will use the same number.

Since you are using C++, use `std::list` and don't waste time creating your own linked list. The `std::list` has already been tested so you don't need to test it.

To read in a menu selection using C++, try:

```
int selection;
cin >> selection;
switch (selection)
{
  //...
}
```